# Brand new WIN10 PC stuttering once powered on

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, performance, lag

I'm having a problem on a brand new assembled PC: video and audio stutters.

This is my build:
**MOBO**
Asus tuf x570-plus
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07TNSYXXV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**CPU**
3800X
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07SXMZLPJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**GPU**
RX 5700 XT
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07TB5FBV6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**STORAGE**
Samsung SSD 850evo

**RAM**
Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO Black DDR4-RAM 3600 MHz 8gb
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07TB3R9JB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

**PSU**
XFX Zasilacz 850W Full Modular 80+ Titanium
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07VJHBXSH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Ok, story is: first I bought the RX 5700 XT and used it with my previous conf (FX8350 + DDR3 ram) without problems, just CPU bottleneck but that's known. Then I bought the other parts and assembled a brand new PC, moving the old SSD to the new build.

I noticed some problems and I decided to fresh reinstall Win10 on SSD, same result, problems still there. I already tried to run Driverbooster7 which has installed some drivers, but nothing changed.

Both CPU and GPU temp are fine (less than 60 deg) and I have a ridiculously low cpu-gpu-ram-disk usages (all things are below 30%), but I still have the problem: mouse teleports and audio/video lagging.

The only strange thing that I saw were my 3600Mhz rams running at 2166Mhz. While I can't understand why, but idk if the problem is there or not.
Has anyone a good suggestion or any idea in order to help solving this boring problem?

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* your RAM is so underclocked. Have you checked in the BIOS/UEFI for some RAM settings? Might be that one or several of your RAM sticks underperform for some reason, and that sets your whole machine in a semi-comatose state from time to time.

Comment: Yah, i checked. All confs are in auto, i tryed to change ram speeds but pc doesn't boot and stucks on DRAM strat. I had to remove CMOS battery to reset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.  The problem seems to be created by installing drivers via Driver Booster (1st time) and installing Radeon drivers before running all the windows updates (2nd time)

I tried to reinstall a fresh version of Windows 10, let all the win updates to be done, and finally installing the Radeon Adrenalins drivers from https://www.amd.com/en/support